# VideoCaptureDevice frame rate

Tags: c#, stream, frame, aforge, rate

I have create a application form using Visual C# language. I use the aforge library to display image from my ip camera. The problem is that if i try to process my image then the video streaming done slow. So the video delay 3-4 second to display. The frame rate is 24fps.
I think if I change the frame rate (for example 4fpm) then the flow will improve. So how can change frame rate using the aforge library.

Here is my code:

```
MJPEGStream mpeg = new MJPEGStream();
                     AForge.Video.DirectShow.VideoCaptureDevice fcg = new AForge.Video.DirectShow.VideoCaptureDevice();                 
                     mpeg.Login = "xxx";
                     mpeg.Password = "xxx";
                     mpeg.Source = "http://192.168.1.xx:xx/videostream.cgi";
                     AsyncVideoSource asyncSource = new AsyncVideoSource(mpeg);                     
                     mpeg.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalVideo_NewFrame);               
                     mpeg.Start();



     void FinalVideo_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
                {
                    video = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
                    DisplaypictureBox.Image = video; 
                }
```